# at risk or in risk ?What's the difference?Thanks

Tags: word-difference

The disease was spreading, and the town's children were _____ risk.

A. in    B. at

Could you tell me the difference between "in risk"  and "at risk".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You use **at risk.**

**At risk** is an idiom that means "to be in a situation where something unpleasant might happen." ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/at-risk))

For example ([nhlbi.nih.gov](https://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health-topics/pneumonia)):

> However, two age groups are **at** greater **risk** of developing
>   pneumonia

If you check .gov sites, you can see, they usually say someone is ["at risk of developing"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=XqfnXMmKIdCXsAfj6qmoBA&q=site%3Agov%20%22at%20risk%20of%20developing%22%20&oq=site%3Agov%20%22at%20risk%20of%20developing%22%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1887.1887..4929...0.0..0.51.51.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.2vqYO9pIydI) a disease and not ["in risk of developing"](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=ZKfnXKzpHorQkwXzx4vwDw&q=site%3Agov%20%22in%20risk%20of%20developing%22&oq=site%3Agov%20%22in%20risk%20of%20developing%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20791.21540..22429...0.0..0.55.216.4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.q-i0ri958jo) a disease.

"In risk" is not wrong, but the idiomatic usage is "at risk."

Answer (score 0):

B is the correct answer, that's how English described it,

Within few searches you can get your result, my first search got it for you, and is B:

> The disease was spreading, and the town's children were at risk.